# Java sempahore options

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I'm writing an application in which there is a possibility of more than one thread trying to modify the same file. To overcome this, I have thought of storing the filenames in a concurrent hashmap, filename<->count and use wait and notify i.e

```
if(map has fileName){
 map.put(fileName, map.get(fileName)++ )
 wait()
}else{
 map.put(fileName,1)
}

modifyFile(fileName);

{
 count = map.get(fileName);
 if count == 1 then map.remove(fileName)
 else map.put(fileName, count-- )
 notify()
}
```

But I don't feel the above code is elegant. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**: A simple lock would block the flow for all threads. I just want to block the threads which want to modify the same file, other threads should be unaffected

Comment: It's hard to tell *exactly* what you want given that what you've written is pseudo-code. Do you need anything more than a simple lock would give you?

Comment: @JonSkeet A simple lock would block the flow for all threads. I just want to block the threads which want to modify the same file, other threads should be unaffected

Comment: No, a simple lock only blocks the threads that are trying to acquire the lock.

Comment: @Joel Yes, by simple lock, we mean the same lock object for all threads

Comment: Are you at all worried about other programs or other JVM's modifying the file? Or just the one JVM you are running in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Unfortunately, the term file is loosely used, right now the resource is a file, but it can be anything later.

Comment: @Rnet: So create a different lock for each file...

Comment: What you are trying to do is dangerous, because there can be multiple different `File` objects that point to the same file (for example with relative and absolute paths), so threads might access the same file at the same time because they use different `File` objects. Even if you force all paths to be absolute, there might still be symlinks or hardlinks so that different threads modify the same file even if they think they are modifying different files.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The documentation of `FileLock` says "They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.", so they are not usable here (this is because they are implemented by the OS, and the OS has only locks with process granularity).

Comment: @JonSkeet, hmm yes, what I've written is similar to what you have suggested

Comment: @Rnet: But using a `synchronized` block would be simpler than using wait and notify...

Comment: @PhilippWendler Yeah, guess I didn't read it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not actually thread-safe. Multiple threads could pass the `if count == 1` check simultaneously before removing the object from the map.

```
java.util.concurrent
```

Contains a Semaphore implementation that would work better. Then simply use a hashmap to store the semaphores. Do not add/remove the semaphores, just access them. Then the synchronization work is done by the semaphores and not your map.

```
modifyFile(fileName);
{
 semaphore = map.get(fileName);
 semaphore.acquire(1);
 doWork();
 semaphore.release(1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, wrote the pseudo code in a hurry. The only problem with the above solution would be that the map starts accumulating objects, and there are > 2k resources/files

Comment: @Rnet: Do you think 2000 objects is really likely to be a problem? While it would be *nice* to clean up as you go along, I probably wouldn't bother unless this is a long-running service.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I guess you are right, but leaving objects to accumulate like that though knowing nothing might happen still feels kinda ..uhm unsatisfactory

Comment: @Rnet: Personally I'd rather write simple code which is obviously correct but leaves a bit of baggage around, than code which needs hours spent checking that it's thread-safe :) It does depend on the kind of app you're writing though.

Comment: How about letting a WeakHashMap do the tidying up for you?